# copy cells to sheet base on criteria match

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I have been working on this project for a while and feel like I am getting so close but an running into issues at the end. I have pulled pieces of this code from different sources. I am happy to say that I am not getting any errors. Unfortunately, I'm not getting results either.

I have two sheets, one has static data (main) and the other is updated weekly vis copy/paste (source) What I am attempting to do is match concatenated data from main to source and copy specific cells on a match. when I run the macro I get results on one line out of 50. The inner loop continues all the way to the bottom of the sheet but the outer loop does not seem to change the row on the target sheet (main) I'm not really sure how one row is being populated. I know I am missing something here but what?

```
Dim wsSource As Worksheet
Dim wsMain As Worksheet
Dim rngs As Variant
Dim rngm As Variant
Dim srow As Integer
Dim mrow As Integer
Dim i As Long
Dim lastrow As Long




Set wsSource = Worksheets("Source")
Set wsMain = Worksheets("Main")

Set rngs = wsSource.Range("L2")
Set rngm = wsMain.Range("L2")





    'Clear old data
    wsMain.Range("D2:L1500").ClearContents
    wsSource.Range("L2:L1500").ClearContents


    wsMain.Range("L2:L" & Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row).FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(RC[-11],RC[-10],RC[-9])"
    wsSource.Range("L2:L" & Range("A65000").End(xlUp).Row).FormulaR1C1 = "=CONCATENATE(RC[-11],RC[-10],RC[-9])"

    lastrow = Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    srow = 2
    mrow = 2


    Do Until rngm.Offset(mrow, 0).Value <> "" And rngm.Offset(mrow, 1).Value <> ""


        Do Until rngs.Offset(srow, 0).Value <> "" And rngs.Offset(mrow, 1).Value <> ""

            If (rngs.Offset(srow, 0).Value = rngm.Offset(mrow, 0).Value) Then

            rngm.Offset(mrow, -8).Value = rngs.Offset(srow, -8).Value
            rngm.Offset(mrow, -7).Value = rngs.Offset(srow, -7).Value
            rngm.Offset(mrow, -6).Value = rngs.Offset(srow, -6).Value
            rngm.Offset(mrow, -5).Value = rngs.Offset(srow, -5).Value
            rngm.Offset(mrow, -4).Value = rngs.Offset(srow, -4).Value
            rngm.Offset(mrow, -3).Value = rngs.Offset(srow, -3).Value
            rngm.Offset(mrow, -2).Value = rngs.Offset(srow, -2).Value
          End If
        srow = srow + 1
        Loop
    mrow = mrow + 1
Loop
```

I will be happy to upload the workbook if there is a way to do that

Answer (score 0):

I find all the range offsetting rather confusing, what happens if you simply offset `rngs` and `rngm`?

```
Set rngs = wsSource.Range("L4") ' L2 offset by (2,0)
Set rngm = wsMain.Range("L4") ' L2 offset by (2,0)

Do Until rngm.Value <> "" And rngm.Offset(0, 1).Value <> ""
    Do Until rngs.Value <> "" And rngs.Offset(0, 1).Value <> ""
        If (rngs.Value = rngm.Value) Then
            wsMain.Range("D" & rngm.row & "J" & rngm.row) = wssource.Range("D" & rngs.row & "J" & rngs.row)
        End If
        Set rngs = rngs.Offset(1,0)
    Loop
    Set rngm = rngm.Offset(1,0)
Loop
```

There's another way to loop through your cells:

```
For i = 5 to wsSource.Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    Set rngm = wsSource.Range("L" & i)
    For j = 5 to wsSource.Range("L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        Set rngs = wsSource.Range("L" & j)
        If (rngs.Value = rngm.Value) Then
            wsMain.Range("D" & i & "J" & i) = wssource.Range("D" & j & "J" & j)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next j
Next i
```

Alternatively:

```
For each rngm in wsSource.Range("L5:L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    For each rgns in wsSource.Range("L5:L" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
        If (rngs.Value = rngm.Value) Then
            wsMain.Range("D" & rngm.row & "J" & rngm.row) = wssource.Range("D" & rngs.row & "J" & rngs.row)
            Exit For
        End If
    Next rngs
Next rngm
```

Should also work

Comment: First, thank you. This seems to want to work until I get to the first match and then I get runtime 438, Object doesn't support  this property or method on the transfer line after then.

Comment: Correction! I entered the code just as in the answer. the first match in wsSource is on the fifth line. the code executes and after the fifth loop I get the error Method 'Range' of 0bject'_worksheet' failed right at the point where it would copy the data. The line right after "Then"@cybernetic.nomad

Comment: This code has worked beautifully.Thank you cybernetic.Now I am racking my brain on a new issue with it. When there is no match in rngs and the loop gets to the bottom it dies. Is there a way to reset it back to the beginning either on a match or if no match. So when it copies the cells on a match or gets to the do until condition it will offset rngm and start at the top of rngs again. I really appreciate the help and I have been searching for an answer for days before posting

Comment: Check out the above code options. Please note that I can't test it on the machine I am on at the moment.

Comment: Thank you again. you are the best, the first code works perfect. Now I'm off to figure out how to exclude empty cells.

Answer (score 0):

*Since you have neither specified the criteria nor attached the sample data. So that I would like to suggest you similar method to copy matched data from one sheet to other.*

**NB:** *This code matches Cell A1 from both sheets, to Copy Data.*

```
Sub Copy&Paste()

Dim sht As Worksheet 
Dim newsht As Worksheet 

Set sht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
Set newsht = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

Set dat = sht.Range("A1")
Set newdat = newsht.Range("A1")

Dim i, j, iRow As Integer   
i = 1
j = 1
iRow = 1

'For Header Row
newdat.Offset(0, 0).Value = dat.Offset(0, 0).Value 
newdat.Offset(0, 1).Value = dat.Offset(0, 2).Value 
newdat.Offset(0, 2).Value = dat.Offset(0, 3).Value 
newdat.Offset(0, 3).Value = dat.Offset(0, 4).Value 
newdat.Offset(0, 4).Value = dat.Offset(0, 5).Value 
newdat.Offset(0, 5).Value = dat.Offset(0, 6).Value 

Do While dat.Offset(i, 0).Value <> "" Or dat.Offset(i, 1).Value <> ""

  j = 1     

  Do While dat.Offset(j, 0).Value <> ""

    If (newdat.Offset(i, 0).Value = dat.Offset(j, 4).Value _
    Or newdat.Offset(i, 1).Value = dat.Offset(j, 5).Value) _
    And dat.Offset(j, 6).Value = "your criteria" Then

    'This copies Data.

      newdat.Offset(iRow, 0).Value = dat.Offset(j, 0).Value 
      newdat.Offset(iRow, 1).Value = dat.Offset(j, 2).Value 
      newdat.Offset(iRow, 2).Value = dat.Offset(j, 3).Value 
      newdat.Offset(iRow, 3).Value = dat.Offset(j, 4).Value 
      newdat.Offset(iRow, 4).Value = dat.Offset(j, 5).Value 
      newdat.Offset(iRow, 5).Value = dat.Offset(j, 6).Value 
      iRow = iRow + 1
    End If
    j = j + 1     
  Loop

  i = i + 1     

Loop

End Sub
```

**Note, with Offset command you can change the data range as your need. Also, this code was tested by me before I've uploaded here.**

*I do hope this help you.*